# What does 活躍話 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

This is perhaps too quick a question but I'm not sure on the meaning and after searching the net I've found nothing to give me confidence in any interpretation. Here is the text that prompted to ask this question:

> そして始まったのが、[如何]{いか}にして最強の忍者を自分が捕えたのかという、[嘘八百]{うそはっぴゃく}のゆきの[活躍話]{かつやくばなし}であった。

活躍 means activity, apparently with a positive connotation of of flourishing or succeeding. While 話 has several meanings, in this case I believe it means story. Mashing the definitions together yields "activity story". That's nonsense in English of course. My question is what's an 'activity story"? A story with lots of action (in other words, an action story)? Or is it something else like "success story"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

活躍 is a word that almost always implies success or great performance. (eg 彼は試合で大活躍した。 = He performed very well in the game.)

I don't think 活躍話 is an established idiom, but 活躍話 in this context clearly means "tale of triumph", "success story", "heroic episode", etc.